# Kivy Application not reformatting when I resize window

Tags: python, kivy

I am just learning Kivy in python and am following a tutorial. I have made a window and have a label saying "hello world". My tutorial shows that when I resize the window, all the contents should reformat accordingly. However, when I resize my window, my label (Which was in the center of the window) moves around to the sides. Any idea why this might be happening, and if so, how do I fix it?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Hello World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Some widgets like `Button` has `size_hint = [1,1]` so it auto resize with window. For `Label` you need to trigger a function with `on_text` command and recalculate his own sizes. Because label is different from Button and you need to resize its own `text_size`. So you should take a look for resizing [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#sizing-and-text-content)

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry for the late reply) That is useful, however, it is only in .kv files. I was looking for just python. I think that this has to do with my version of kivy. Or I'm not following the tutorial correctly. I will edit my question to include more information.